# Aggregation function group_by for categorical features

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, categorical-data

In a record of daily purchases, I want to apply an aggregation function that keeps the "most" important transaction of the day, with the arbitrary order given by `['Bananas', 'Apples', 'Coke', 'Lollipop', 'Chewing gum']`.

```
D   T   ITEM 
1   3   Apples         
1   5   Chewing gum  
1   10  Lollipop   
2   2   Bananas   
2   3   Apples   
2   1   Coke
```

Desired output

```
D   T   ITEM    
1  18  Apples   
2   6  Bananas
```

Is there an x function I could use here in --- 
`groupby['D'].agg({'T':'sum', 'ITEM':x)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert the column ITEM to [Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) with the order from your list end then use `min` in `agg` like:

```
order =  ['Bananas', 'Apples', 'Coke', 'Lollipop', 'Chewing gum']
print (df.assign(ITEM=lambda x: pd.Categorical(x['ITEM'], 
                                               categories=order, 
                                               ordered=True))
         .groupby('D')
         .agg({'T':'sum', 'ITEM':'min'}))
    T     ITEM
D             
1  18   Apples
2   6  Bananas
```